# C++ gethostbyname error No such file or directory

Tags: c++, linux, arm

I use arm ld-linux-armhf.so.3 excute program on aarch system. When I call gethostbyname failed with   No such file or directory

```
char host[100] = "www.google.com";
struct hostent *hp;
if ((hp=gethostbyname(host)) == NULL){
    cout<<"gethostbyname\t"<<-2<<endl;
    if(errno!=0)
    {
        cout<<"gethostbyname\t"<<errno<<endl;
        cout<<"gethostbyname\t"<<strerror(errno)<<endl;
    }
}
```

Print

```
gethostbyname   -2
gethostbyname   2
gethostbyname   No such file or directory
```

/etc/resolve.conf

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

/etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1 AIBox
1.1.1.1 www.google.com
```

How do I know which file is not found?

Changed  to h_errno.

```
char host[100] = "www.google.com";
struct hostent *hp;
if ((hp=gethostbyname(host)) == NULL){
    cout<<"gethostbyname\t"<<-2<<endl;
    if(errno!=0)
    {
        cout<<"gethostbyname\t"<<h_errno<<endl;
        cout<<"gethostbyname\t"<<hstrerror(h_errno)<<endl;
    }
}
```

Print

```
gethostbyname   -2
gethostbyname   3
gethostbyname   Unknown server error
```

Comment: The linux docs seem to indicate you should be looking at h_errno rather than errno.

Comment: @paxdiablo I user wireshark capture packet,I found it never search dns server

Comment: Kaive, Whether it goes out to a DNS server depends on your name resolution pathways. I believe this is controlled by `/etc/nsswitch.conf`. In an extreme case, this could be set up to use `/etc/hosts` only. Your best bet would be to start with that file and work forward.

Comment: @paxdiablo Except for programs using  ld-linux-armhf.so.3, the DNS of other programs are normal.

Comment: And what do you see when you execute `nslookup www.google.com 8.8.8.8`? Please also *add* your `/etc/nsswitch.conf` file to the question. I didn't mention that for the fun of it, it may actually have a bearing on your problem :-)

Comment: It's probably not affecting your results, but you should save `errno` in a local variable before you write to `cout`.  `errno` is only guaranteed to be valid immediately after the call that failed.